# WebUI Popover cannot set title using html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I gave up on Bootstrap popover, and went looking. I found [WebUI Popover](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover) which has all the functionality i am looking for.

But I am having trouble setting the title of the popover using the html content of an element on the page. I get `undefined` in `console.log()` and the title loads empty. The html I am trying to access is dynamically created.

Where I think there is a bug in the plugin is that the content loads perfectly from another element on the page.

[I have a FIDDLE here.](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/tyqosLg2/)

My WebUI Popover code is:

```
   // Popover Menu initialize
   $('.icon-popover-menu').webuiPopover({
     placement: 'left',
     trigger: 'click',
     closeable: true,
     multi: false,
     animation: 'pop',
     cache: 'false',
     type: 'html',
     width: '220',
     title: function() {
       return $(this).closest('td.row-icon').find('.btn-row-popover-menu-head').html();
     },
     content: function() {
       return $(this).closest('td.row-icon').find('.btn-row-popover-menu-body').html();
     }
   });

   // Hide popover when screen changes size
   $(window).on('resize', function() {
     WebuiPopovers.hideAll();
   });
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
     WebuiPopovers.hideAll();
   });
```

A sample of my HTML is:

```
<table class="fiddle">
  <tr>
    <td class="row-icon">
      <button class="icon-popover-menu ion-fw btn-row-popover-menu">BTN</button>
      <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="btn-row-popover-menu-head">
          <span>THIS IS THE TITLE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-row-popover-menu-body">
          <div class="input-group" role="group">
            <a class="btn btn-app btn-icon-menu btn-popover-first" href="#">
              EDIT
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-app btn-icon-menu-danger" href="#">
              DELETE
              <br>
              <span class="transaction-menu-legend">DELETE</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title: function() {
       return  $(event.target).closest('td.row-icon').find('.btn-row-popover-menu-head').html();
     },`

This works fine. By doing `$(this)` you are trying to access the title element of the popover which obviously has no closest `td.row-icon`. Hence it is undefined.

Comment: Hi @Surya, the table has many rows crated dynamically from the back end db. I cannot point it to the class as it needs to be the one for the current row. Also, the same command works for the body. If I use the command from the body onto the title, it is also undefined.

Comment: Will the buttons also be different for each row?

Comment: Hi @Surya, I just updated the fiddle to show how the multiple rows. Yes different buttons in each row. Why does the content work and not the title?

Comment: Cannot. back end is out of my reach. Why does $this work for content and not for title?

Comment: Give ids to your buttons like `<button class="icon-popover-menu ion-fw btn-row-popover-menu" id="btn1">BTN1</button>` and then use the event to get the ids of the buttons to access the title `return  $("#"+event.target.id).closest('td.row-icon').find('.btn-row-popover-menu-head').html();`

Comment: ok to simplify this will work `return  $(event.target).closest('td.row-icon').find('.btn-row-popover-menu-head').html();`

Comment: $(this) as I explained gives you the reference of webpopover title element not the button user clicked

Comment: You rock @Surya, thanks! Can You please change your answer above and I will accept it. Perfect

Comment: Done. Please check :).